# HTML simple form working in FF but in other browsers

Tags: html, forms

I have a simple for in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="windows-1252" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MY TITLE HERE</title>    
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//d14mva318gt4k0.cloudfront.net/js/html5.js?20150804"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//d14mva318gt4k0.cloudfront.net/js/respond.min.js?20150804"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//d14mva318gt4k0.cloudfront.net/js/PIE.js?20150804"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="//d14mva318gt4k0.cloudfront.net/css/ie.css?20150804">
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <div id="ie6msg">
        <p><strong>Your browser is no longer supported.</strong></h4>
        <p>Please, consider upgrading to a more modern browser:</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/" target="_blank"><img src="//www.google.com/tools/dlpage/res/chrome/images/chrome-16.png" height="16" width="16" alt="Google Chrome favicon" /> Google Chrome</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/" target="_blank"><img src="//www.mozilla.com/favicon.ico" height="16" width="16" alt="Mozilla Firefox favicon" /> Mozilla Firefox</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.apple.com/safari/" target="_blank"><img src="//www.apple.com/favicon.ico" height="16" width="16" alt="Safari favicon" /> Safari</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.microsoft.com/ie/" target="_blank"><img src="//www.microsoft.com/nz/windows/Framework/images/favicon.ico" height="16" width="16" alt="Internet Explorer 10 favicon" /> Internet Explorer 10</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <![endif]-->
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
        var appId = '******';
        var channelUrl = '*********';
        </script>    
        <div class="account-area ie-fix">
          <div class="headbar">
              <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>  Supercharge your Premier Membership!  </h2>
          </div><!-- headbar -->
          <section class="section ie-fix" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
              <div class="headline ie-fix">
                  <h3 id="membership_amount" style="font-size:24px;line-height:34px;letter-spacing:.1em;"> Add Elite Features </h3>
              </div><!-- headline -->
              <p style="font-size:16px;">*Normal Elite renewal rate:  $8.00/month</p>

              <div class="general-account" >
                  <div>
                      <div>
                          <form method="post" style="text-align:center;" action="/checkout/">
                              <input type="hidden" name="elite_checkout" value="1" />
                              <input style="margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:0px;padding:12px 20px;font-size:18px;width:auto;height:auto;min-width:235px;" type="submit" name="upgrade" value="Upgrade to Elite" class="btn btn-danger btn-xlarge ie-fix" />
                          </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </section>
          <img style="border-radius:10px;max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="/images/bandmix-bv-elite-checkout.jpg" /><br />
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I post it and run

```
print_r($_POST);
```

I only get an empty array.

The weirdest part is it works fine in Firefox, but not in other browsers.

Some HTML error I'm missing?

UPDATE:

Removed some unused JS from the code and added the name attribute to the button , but still not working...

Didn't include CSS and JS tags in the HTML provided since I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Have you tried validating it e.g. on http://validator.w3.org?

Comment: Yeah. Nothing in there.
Another weird fact, it doesn't work at first, then suddenly it starts working and everything is rainbows and butterflies.

Comment: Can you extend your code snipped in your question to be complete (yet still minimal), including `DOCTYPE`, `<head>...</head>` and what else is needed to get validation to pass?

Answer (score 0):

Good news is my HTML skills are fine, the bad news is I lost almost 2 hours finding a simple bug (every developer's life in a nutshell)

The PHP code getting the form checked if it was using HTTPS, if not it was redirected to the HTTPS url and in that redirection the form values were lost, of course.